# Cakephp Auth: $this->Auth->loginError message

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using Auth Component. I am setting $this->Auth->loginError in the beforeFilter. But i have another posibility. If the user entered username and password is correct but User.status = 'pending' how can i can show a different message. i am using $this->Auth->userScope to set that. but how to show different $this->Auth->loginError for these two posibilities.

1. Username and Password = correct but Status = pending
2. Either Username or Password = incorrect but status = active

there are the two posibilities.

Comment: @RSK nope. I got to know from the MIRC that the AUTH component does the login process in one query so its not possible. and we will have to modify the process. or we will have to do queries and do it.

Comment: thankz for u'r time. Me too struck with the same problem. I am planning to avoid  `$this->Auth->userScope` and check it manually in login function in users controller. It will work fine na? :-)

Comment: yeah or u can do a double check one with just username, password.. then tell ok.. username and password is right. then underscope.. if its correct he is active and correct. else he hasnt activated the account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [autoRedirect property](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)

If you set this to false, you can add some additional logic to the login method in the controller for the model you're using for authentication.  Here you can make the check for the account status and deliver the custom message for the active vs. pending accounts.  You'll have to set redirects manually in the method when autoRedirect is off.